# Migrate to CentOS Stream 9

Tags: centos, centos7, centos6, centos8, centos6.5

As we know CentOS 7 will be EOL in June the 24th. I currently have 7.9 core installed in my network, however because of the EOL and other security risks I was wondering what my best option would be. Therefore I would like to have your guys opinion on this.

Should i:

- Migrate to the latest centos version c9s? (Complete reinstall?)
- something else?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please note Stack Overflow is for programming questions.  I think your question seems more suited for Serverfault or SuperUser.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends a lot on your environment, acceptable risk, sw you running, familarity with OS and so.
I'm in a similar position, need to migrate to something else.
On some less important system I moved on to Centos stream and some are now on Rocky.
Since I'm running ubuntu at work I moved to ubuntu 22.04 LTS on some.
Was going for Debian for my backup server but hit a snag with that to run bacula on debian I have to cmpile from source if I want dedup to work.

Upgrade is often easier than complete reinstall but reinstall is also a good time to look for upgrading the sw to use. If you go with upgrade or rolling upgrade you may end up with a pile of old software that is no longer used but still hang around.

So, without knowing more about your environment no one but you can figure out the best route.